# Regex issue on pattern matching

Tags: regex, pattern-matching

I have a question on regex.
I have a text file that contains meta-urls in the following form:
    www.abc.com/.*services/ 
    www.abc.com/.*/wireless

I want to compare all the patterns from that file with my URL, and execute an action if I find a match. This matching process is hard to understand for me.

Assuming splitarray[0] contains the first line of text file:

```
            String url = page.getWebURL().getURL();         
            URL url1 = new URL(url);
```

how can we compare url1 with splitarray[0]?

**UPDATED**

```
BufferedReader readbuffer = null;
        try {
            readbuffer = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("filters.txt"));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        String strRead;


        try {
            while ((strRead=readbuffer.readLine())!=null){
                String splitarray[] = strRead.split(",");
                String firstentry = splitarray[0];
                String secondentry = splitarray[1];
                String thirdentry = splitarray[2];
                //String fourthentry = splitarray[3];
                //String fifthentry = splitarray[4];
                System.out.println(firstentry + " " + secondentry+ " " +thirdentry);
                URL url1 = new URL("http://www.abc.com/ship/reach/news-and");

                Pattern p = Pattern.compile("http://www.abc.com/.*/reach");
                Matcher m = p.matcher(url1.toString());

                if (m.matches()) {
                  //Do whatever
                    System.out.println("Yes Done");
                }



                }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

But if I want that any url which start with the pattern giving in the splitarray[0]. how can I  implement this?

Comment: What file are you talking about when you say "that file"?  Do you have a text file with a list of regex patterns?

Comment: I think that file means those two urls in the top.

Comment: You mean that the last url somehow is related to the ship/w one?

Comment: Is there a programming language or server type involved here? Edit your question to include more details

Comment: I don't understand your code. First you said your text file has meta urls (what is this?) And none of them look like a regex. Then in your code example you get them and put them into an array but uses them for nothing, instead you compile some regex and use it to match your url. Nothing makes sense. I think you must provide a clear example.

Comment: You are missing a step here. You first need to translate your URLs to a regular expression, or design a method to use those URLs, then only can you compare your URL url1 to those patterns.

Based on the patterns you have shown, I assume you are designing software for a abc solution, like their routers. Therefore, your URLs probably fall in a simple pattern style, like http://www.abc.com/regular-expression-here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the problem after looking on some example in this website.

http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-and-parse-csv-file-in-java/